# Не создается класс js [Uncaught ReferenceError: cell is not defined(…)]

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Как обычно создаю класс, но пишет `Uncaught ReferenceError: cell is not defined(…)`

```js
var copyStyle = false;
    var cell = [];

    $('#sheet1__A2').mousedown(function() {
        $('.font-block .font-bold, .align-block .align-middle, .align-block .align-center').addClass('active-block')
    });

    $('.copy-block .clear').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active-block');
        copyStyle = true;
        console.log('clear');
    });

    $('.default').mousedown(function(){
        if (copyStyle) {
            console.log($(this));
            cell.push($(this));
            $('.default').bind('hover.selectCell', function() {
                cell.push($(this));
            });
        }
    }).mouseup(function(){
        if (copyStyle) {
            $('.default').unbind('hover.selectCell');
            for (var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
                cell[i].css({
                    'background-color' : '#ccc'
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: на какой строке ошибка? В приведенном коде такой ошибки быть не может. Постарайтесь предоставить [mcve]

Comment: @Grundy в консоле ошибок нету, до того времени пока я не вызову массив. К примеру `cell[0]`

Comment: то есть код который добавлен в вопрос работает? тогда в чем ошибка? где вызывается _cell[0]_? Что нужно сделать с предоставленным кодом чтобы ошибка воспроизвелась?

Comment: @Grundy это весь код js который используется, пока. После выполнения условий, по которых `copyStyle` = true; А потом в консоле я пишу `cell[0]` чтобы проверить значения

Comment: где находится этот код и как вы его запускаете?

Comment: @Grundy на локалке. Просто подключаю, как всегда, в конце страницы

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39875/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в областях видимости.

В файле данный код расположен внутри `$(document).ready(function() {...})`.

При вводе в консоль `cell[0]` эта переменная ищется в глобальной области видимости, в то время как нужная переменная объявлена в локальной для вызова `$(document).ready`.

Решений может быть несколько, например

1. не набирать в консоли, а выводить с использованием `console.log` или подобных функций
2. сделать переменную `cell` глобальной.
3. поставить точку остановки внутри нужной функции, и в момент остановки область видимости в консоли будет соответствовать нужной.